# Menu overlapping media player object

Tags: javascript, html, media-player, media

I am using the object tag to play media on my web page. I have a menu in the same page(with absolute positioning) which when hovered doesn't overlap the media player object. So the contents of the menu are not fully visible.

I found similar questions on StackOverflow which suggested to use (wmode="opaque") for the object tag but it's not working for me.

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

The above line is added in the fiddle.Still it's not working. Here is the jsfiddle link for the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/akonchady/8LDtN/5/

Please tell me how I can make the menu contents fully visible.